# How to locate corresponding arrayList entries from textfile in Java14

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've run into a problem with my code. I'm reading employer information out of a text file. There are fifteen total employees with corresponding names, age, and department. Each department has 5 employees. Example of txt file:

```
|Kyle; 35; Floral |
|John; 40; Meat   |
|Alex; 25; Dairy  |
|Matt; 30; Floral |
|Jill; 45; Floral |
| ...             |
```

These 3 pieces of information(name,age,dept) are stored into an array list that has 15 elements.

The program firsts asks for the department:
Ex:

```
Where is the employee located?
1. Floral
2. Meat
3. Dairy
```

*inputs 1*
Choosing a number only lists the employees of the department.

```
Which employee in Floral would you like to view information?
1. Kyle
2. Matt
3. Jill
4. ...
5. ...
```

This is the issue. I need a way to track the employee's element in array list and display contents. For example, picking Matt would correspond to ArrayList element of [0]. Is there a way to connect ArrayList elements in such a way that you can split them up in categories and subcategories?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> These 3 pieces of information(name,age,dept) are stored into an array list that has 15 elements.

No, mixing various pieces of data across elements of a single list is a poor choice of data structure.

Being [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), Java lets you define a class as your own custom data type.

In Java 16, this has become much easier when the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature enables a very brief class definition. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, accessor methods, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
public record Employee ( String name , int age , String department ) {}
```

Make your list of employees.

```java
List< Employee > employees = new ArrayList<>() ;
employees.add( new Record ( "Kyle" , 35 , "Floral" ) ) ;
employees.add( new Record ( "John" , 40 , "Meat" ) ) ;
…
```

Loop those to generate your menu.

```java
int nth = 0 ;
for( Employee employee : employees )
{
    nth ++ ;
    Sytem.out.println( nth + employee.name() ) ;
}
```

Subtract one from the user's choice of one-based ordinal number to get a zero-based index number.

```java
int userChoice = … ;
int index = ( userChoice - 1 ) ;
Employee employee = employees.get( index ) ;
System.out.println( employee ) ;
```

If you want to narrow the list to employees of a certain department, make another list.

```java
String targetDepartment = … ;
List< Employee > employeesForOneDept = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( Employee employee : employees )
{
    if( employee.department().equals( targetDepartment ) )
    {
        employeesForOneDept.add( employee ) ;
    }
}
```

There are more sophisticated ways to go about this. But as a beginner, this is a good way to start.